# How to solve the javascript get value in URl

Tags: javascript

for my form

```
window.location="xxx.php?id="+id;
```

The value of id is displayed in URL like this

localhost/filename.php?**id=2**.

i didnt want to show the URL value `id=2`.

how to convert the value like `localhost/filename.php?**id=XZsaswee..** like this. Please Help me.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: when i pass the value it should be converted into different format.

Comment: And how is "XZsaswee" converted to "2"?

Comment: What kind of a format? What function does the value have? What language are you using on server side? This is too little to go with.

Comment: You can use encodeURI for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: Do you just want to obfuscate the id?

Comment: use base64_encode() and base64_decode() for encoding and decoding the value of id in php

Comment: Could you tell how to use base64_encode() . Thanks @DS9

Comment: Thanks @DKM. encodeURI for string. But my value is integer. how to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some stuf like making some operations on the id before sendin it, but these operations should be reversable (multiply, devide ...) to do the same thing on the server side to know what's the real number wich is sent by the View. Hope it Helps

Comment: could you give me one example. how to do like that one.

Answer (score 0):

put your value in `base64_encode` function.it encode the your value.
use this for encoding:
suppose

```
$id="2";
base64_encode($id);
```

now ,

localhost/filename.php?id=`$id`.

and decode it using

```
base64_decode($id);
```

Comment: it is php function..not javascript